# Resize Image with upload in PHP

Tags: php, image

Here is my working image upload and rename code, I however need some assistance to resize the image that is being uploaded.

Upload Code:

```
// Upload File to Directory
    $code = md5(time());
    $image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $imagename = $code.$image;
    $file_name = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploaddir = '../_gallery/' . $imagename;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Store to MySQL:

```
$sql="UPDATE b_thome SET 
hdescription = '$front_description', 
himg = '$uploadfile', 
hndescription = '$right_description', 
hfacebook='$facebook_link', 
htwitter='$twitter_link' 
WHERE locationid = '$location'";
```

Is there a easy way to resize the image set 600 x 800px?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library to resize it, it offers all the function you could ask for images management. With it you could use a function like this to create a image that is a reduction of the first one:

```
function resizeImage($file, $filename, $newwidth = 800, $newheight = 600)
{       
    $type = substr($file,strrpos($file,".")+1);

    switch($type) 
    {
        case 'jpg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
    }

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($file);
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    switch($type) {
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'png':
            imagepng($tmp,$filename,9);
            break;
        case 'wbm':
            imagewbmp($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        default:
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're lazy, there is a good open source project called [PHP Image Magican](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/) that makes image resizing nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [PHP GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to resize an image on upload